# difference between malloc vs uint8_t

Tags: c, memory, malloc, fwrite, fread

newbie to C language here. I am not sure of the difference between allocating memory to a file through malloc, and doing

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE filename[//number of bytes]
```

For instance reading the start of a file and checking for jpeg, we are using the latter to check for the first 4 bytes for its "signature". This involves "fread" function in order to read the first 4 bytes and temporarily store it in this place called filename. Won't I be doing the same thing with malloc? Not sure what is the exact difference between the 2.

Thanks everyone in advance for answering my question!

Comment: You need a good book on C. `malloc` is a dynamic memory allocation function. Only in the he farthest stretches of imagination is it related to file io, and there generally only when managing the memory you're transferring data to/from the file stream. There are other ways to provide memory when doing said-same io, including using automatic storage space or global/static storage space. The exceptionally brief tow lines you show is using one of those.

Comment: This question, in correct form, should be "the difference b/w memory status of `malloc` & memory status of predefined array of the form `[]`." When `BYTE fname[5]` is used, consecutive 5 memory spaces, each 8 bytes long, will be allocated as soon as the executable is loaded into memory. When `BYTE *fname = malloc(5 * sizeof(uint8_t))` is used, related 5 memory spaces will be allocated at run time, i.e. when the corresponding `malloc` statement is reached.

Comment: `typedef uint8_t BYTE;` is horrible practice. You _should_ use the idiomatic standardized type `uint8_t` and not invent some secret, local type standard.